# Customize Lock Screen

Tags: screen-lock

When I lock my screen, sometimes it shows my iTunes library, other times it shows a screensaver, and other times it shows photos.

I don't want it to do any of these things, I'd like it to just show a black background or maybe a picture.

Is there a way to customize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a system preference, and you change it in the Desktop & Screensaver pane of... **System Preferences**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't know it was a screensaver.  I'm used to Windows, where the Lock Screen and screensaver are two different things.

Comment: @bassplayer Album art won't show up if you pick a screensaver other than the “iTunes Artwork” one.

Comment: dude honestly, the simplest google search would have told you about this...

Comment: Oops (gulp), for some reason I thought we were talking about the iPhone. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [Lock Screen 2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-screen-2/id445423011?mt=12) app for macs to customize your lock screen. It costs only $1.99 (on sale now, regular $4.99) and you can make it look and behave identical to your iPhone/iPod-Touch/iPad lock screens. [Here](http://www.cultofmac.com/114677/app-brings-the-ios-lock-screen-to-your-mac/) is a more detailed review of the app.

[image]